# Why does FFT accelerate the calculation involved in convolution?

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I am seeing a lot of literature in which they say that by using the fft one can reach a faster convolution. I know that one needs to get fft and and then ifft from the results, but I really do not understand why using the fft can make the convolution faster?

Comment: FFT is faster than direct convolution if the convolution's kernel is "large".  This is explained in a question on Programmer's SE  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/171757/4280

Answer (score 6):

FFT speeds up convolution for large enough filters, because convolution requires N multiplications (and N-1) additions for each output sample and conversely (2)N^2 operations for a block of N samples.

Taking account, that one has to double the block size for FFT processing by adding zeroes, each block requires (2)*(2N)*log(2N) operations to perform FFT, 2N operations to multiply and again 4N*log(2N) operations to perform inverse FFT, there is a break even point, where 8Nlog2N <= 2N^2.

The fundamental reasons are:

1) a discrete time-domain signal can be represented as a sum of frequencies.
2) convolution in time domain (O(N^2)) equals multiplication of frequencies in frequency  domain (O(N))
3) the transformation is invertible
4) there exists a method to convert a signal from time domain to frequency domain in less than N^2 operations (that's the first F in 'Fast Fourier Transform').

The straight forward FT is O(N^2), where each Frequency domain element F(i) = Sigma f(i) * exp(i*pi/N).

However the FFT is based on an observation that exp(i*pi/N) has certain symmetries, allowing the calculation to be split in odd/even vectors. The even vectors can be calculated at the expense of O(N) while the odd vectors require a full FT of half the size. As this can be repeated until N=2, the overall complexity will be (proportional to) Nlog(N).

Comment: A word of caution: the primary operations in FFT are also complex (meaning that a complex multiplication requires 4 real multiplications and 2 additions, or 3 multiplications and 5 additions with Karatsuba decomposition) Anyway KNlog(kN) will be eventually smaller than N^2.

Comment: So, why the computational cost in fft space is smaller than time, I mean, does it use a smaller pieces of data or it is something else? What is your mean by filters?

Comment: FFT has to use larger blocks.

Comment: -1.  This explanation is incomplete, incorrect, and misleading.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171757/computational-complexity-of-correlation-in-time-vs-multiplication-in-frequency-s for a better explanation.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, please read that link.  You've collapsed everything into N, which obscures the real issue.  In typical image filtering, you have a large image that is WxW (using terminology of that link) and a filter that is KxK.  This is already assuming square.  The benefit of FFT in convolution is a function of how big K is with respect to W.  It's simple-minded to collapse everything into N, and that obscures the real issue.  In fact, matlab's conv2 function **does not** use FFT for this reason.  In most image filtering applications, K << W.

Comment: Also would like to point out that the author of the answer in that link incorrectly underestimated the run time of 2-dimensional FFT.  While 2D Fourier Transform (FT) has the advantage of being separable, there is a little bit of an overhead.  2D FT of a WxW image is not the same as 1D FT of a W*W vector, but it's close.

Comment: did you see the part where it says "K^2 < 8*log(W)"? In fact, he underestimated the size of the kernel where it is advantageous to convolve directly, but it's certainly more correct than yours. Your equation for "large enough filters" 8Nlog2N <= 2N^2 (simplifies to 4+4log N <= N) is incorrect.

Comment: @thang: I read that link, but it seems that he/she eventually proof that the computational cost of fft is more than simple convolution! Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DarenW, can you chime in?  It's your answer! :p

Comment: Do you have a link with these formulas?