# How does filter2D function in OpenCV perform more efficient than my own convolution code?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to write my own code in C++ to achieve convolution. 
And the kernel is 11 by 11 and not separable. So my code is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j){
       int tmp, sum; 
       for(int m= 0; m < kernel.rows; ++m){
          for(int n = 0; n < kernel.cols; ++n){
             tmp = image[i+m-(Size_kernel-1)/2][j+n-(Size_kernel-1)/2];
             float kernel_index = kernel[m][n];
             float index_mult = (float)index_mult * kernel_index;
             sum = sum + index_mult;
          }
       }
      new_image[i][j] = sum; 
    }
 }
```

We can see the complexity of this piece  of code is big. And it is very slow when I run the program.

However, when I plug in the two matrices into "filter2D" function in OpenCV. It takes very short time to show the result. Can anyone explain how filter2D in OpenCV achieves convolution? Why there is big difference in efficiency between OpenCV and my own code? Thanks!

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597845/why-fft-accelerate-the-convolution-calculation

Comment: Note that your code is buggy, because you never initialise `sum`. As for performance, any decent 2D filter implementation will use SIMD, and for large enough kernels a frequency-domain implementation will be faster than a direct implementation. And finally: don't forget to enable compiler optimisations (e.g. `gcc -O3 ...`) - it makes a big difference for code such as the above.

Comment: @vsoftco So is the OpenCV function using fft to achieve 2d convolution?

Comment: @PaulR Thank you. I have used the compiler optimisations. It performs better but still much slower than the OpenCV code...What is frequency-domain implementation? Can you explain it a little bit, or provide any pseudo code, or any reference for that?

Comment: See the question linked to by @vsoftco above. I'm not sure it will be helpful for a small-ish filter like 11x11 though. SIMD optimisation is probably the way to go if you've done everything you can to optimise your scalar code. Post your actual code though in case there are any remaining optimisations that can be exploited.

Comment: @PaulR I have updated my actual code. I will look at the link. Can you also help me check my code to see any possible optimization?

Comment: That doesn 't look like it could be the actual code - there are several obvious bugs. Please post the actual code and also include the declarations for the input and output image, the kernel and the local variables - it looks like you may be doing a lot of inefficient mixed int/float arithmetic but it's hard to tell with incomplete code.

Comment: The question implementation is pretty naive, a lot of room for improvements, mostly by parallelism. SIMD was already called, multithreading is an option too for this expensive task and Cuda or OpenCL brings the most. The algorithm itself can be improved for large kernels by FFT (as already mentioned too), indexing replaced by pointer arithmetic, aligned memory used, an optimized convolution function built during runtime (by jit), casts done in sequence (->temporary image with floats), ...